# How can I add a bumpy glowing surface to my model?

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials

How can I achieve this surface and light on sphere's? Picture below:

[image: Not smooth surface]

I appreciate help, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2579/32194). It doesn't describe the glow effect, but that's a simple thing to add in compositing.

Answer (score 4):

[image: This node set up should get you started. The actually "glow" part would be done in post.]

This is very basic but should get you going in the correct direction. I also added a subdivision surface of 2, the "multiply" node is just a "math" node set to mulitply. The actual glowing part would be done in post. Or you can switch out the glossy node with an emission shader and see if that looks ok when you add more of the bumpy balls.