# Microscopic Shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I'm wondering how can I do a microscopic shader like in this picture. I tried to sculpt to simulate it, but its not satisfying. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to model it or how to build a shader for it?

Comment: i have already a geometry. shader.

Comment: "not satisfying" is a hard thing to understand. Can you add an image of what you have so far?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/microscopic-material-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23571/what-is-this-kind-of-material